# transaction failed / no confirmations

Tags: transaction-confirmation, transaction-failed

Have latest version 0.17.1.1-33afd0b, but transactions dont go confirmed. After several minutes are back in original wallet and confirmations are nr 0.

I restored into new wallet, didnt helped.

Comment: what is you wallet ? plz say name wallet and OS device

Comment: Its GUI WALLET on Win 10, 64 bit

Comment: and interesting, yesterday letf one transaction, but today again nothing.. all is connected

Comment: @Karl - which `Wallet mode` are you using?